# Mobaxterm bookmarks folders etc created with script?

Tags: mobaxterm

Has someone already created structures bookmarks with folders and all the stuff for mobaxterm?

We do have a large installation and mobaxterm seems to be the tool for the last line of defense.
Therefore I would like to script some of the creation and looking for some hints, description and so on.

Answer (score 2):

Question was asked long ago (7months) but maybe someone will come here looking for the same thing.
I'm assuming you're asking about bookmarks of directories to access through SSH for example (i.e. going to directory /home/thisuser/preferedfolder with one click)

As of today I don't know any regular way to achieve bookmarks with MobaXterm.
However, as a workaround, I've managed to mimic the same behaviour with Macros.

Just record a **macro** with "cd /home/thisuser/preferedfolder" in it. You will later go to that "bookmark" in one click on the macro.
Note that you can edit a recorded macro which I find easier than recording live typing, as you can copy and paste path.

Also avoid using "TAB" key because you can have unexpected result if your directory structure changes.

Answer (score 0):

Using macro is limited for MobaXterm free edition. Another way is using 'Execute Command' after connect features, don't forget to tick 'Do not exit after command ends'.

Look at this image
[image]